# PHP - Codeigniter - How to delete file with some name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have image files with the name like this:
200x200-myimage1.jpg,
300x300-myimage1.jpg,
200x200-myimage2.jpg.

in location uploads/thumbs/thread/

I want to delete the file that only contain the name of myimage1.jpg.

i have done using glob like hsz answered like this:

```
$image_name = "myimage1.jpg";
foreach(glob('./uploads/thumbs/thread/'.$image_name) as $rows) {                
    unlink($rows);        
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Could you help me?

**edit**
solved
i forget to add * before my $image_name.
so it will become like this:
`glob('./uploads/thumbs/thread/*'.$image_name)`

Comment: ANd what did you try so far? People won't just write the code for you - but will be happy once you show some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out all files that contain `myimage1` in the name, use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)

```
foreach (glob("*myimage1*") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```