# overwrite file with codeigniter regardless of file extension

Tags: php, codeigniter

I really need help here. I have successfully achieved the task of uploading an image on server but I need to overwrite image with same name regardless of extension. I am using codeigniter which provides the following:

```
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
```

But the above code only works when the filename is same including the extension.
Please help. I'm really passionate about my project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite `myImage.JPG` with 'myImage.PNG` if they upload that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Comment: I don't think you can as they are different files. The only thing I can think of is writing a small script to delete any of myimage.png, myimage,jpg, myimage,gif, myimage,tif etc etc. if you have a successful upload. This is such a strange request that perhaps you need to rethink how you are approaching whatever it is you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I tried deleting the files using the unlink() function but seems like that function then restricts the json data(the upload path and filename) that I'm sending back to client side. Really need a good workaround.

Comment: This answer helped me figure it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476694/php-codeigniter-how-to-delete-file-with-some-name